# Is there a way to set jQuery resizable containment to own figures.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-resizable

As the Question implies, I need a way to set my own resizable containment of an element. jQuery only has the parent option which is not an option in this project. SO is there any way to set containment on a resizable element to specific figures instead of the parent or another element..?

```
        $(e).resizable({
            containment:'parent'// i wonna set my own figures instead....
        });
```

Comment: There seem to be a [bunch of options](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-containment) for containment

Comment: Where is one..?

Comment: You could give it a selector with the containment element.  You could define the containment later on when new elements exist.  etc.

Comment: @James, Dude you are a Genius! Thanks...

Answer (score -1):

you can apply jquery resizable directly to img tag.

```
      <img id="resizable" src="ur image url" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
  } );
  </script>
```

please refer:
http://jsbin.com/jiwehasofo/1/edit?html,output